# Playing a Facebook video in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, facebook-graph-api, video

My application is making API calls to Facebook and returning video URLs, for example:

https://video.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t43.1792-2/17641656_1853451031583994_2664925858824716288_n.mp4?efg=eyJybHIiOjI1OTIsInJsYSI6MTAyNCwidmVuY29kZV90YWciOiJzdmVfaGQifQ%3D%3D&rl=2592&vabr=1728&oh=d503ccbcfe165a8cfc0436fb0a07078e&oe=58E04780

The video uses the H.264 codec.

Is there a way I can get this video to play from the URL in WPF without having to download the video locally?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you use MediaElement to display videos without downloading. Please check this url  http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/audio-video/playing-video/

Comment: I did try setting the URL as the source but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try on [WebBrowser](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-webbrowser-control/) control.

**In xaml:**

```
<WebBrowser Name="wbSample"></WebBrowser>
```

**In CodeBehind:**

```
wbSample.Navigate("<<your url>>");
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, this brings up a download prompt for the video in question.